# Is it possible to specify a named route within a resourceful route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, named-routing

I'm just upgrading my app to Rails 3 and as I have to rewrite my routing anyway, I'm taking some time to improve my named routes.

I have an invoices controller which has a trash action (/invoices/trash lists all invoices in trash). I want to access this through a named route (i.e. trash_url) for simplicity in my views.

I can achieve this easily enough with the following

```
match "/invoices/trash" => "invoices#trash", :as => :trash
```

What I want to know is if there is a way of doing this within the block where I define the routes for my invoice controller. I have tried the following and it doesn't work.

```
resources :invoices do
  collection do
    get :trash, :as => :trash
  end
end
```

Is what I am trying to do possible or do I have to define my named route outside of this block?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you list (shown below) works fine for me, it generates `trash_invoices_path` and `trash_invoices_url` helper methods.

```
resources :invoices do
  collection do
    get :trash, :as => :trash
  end
end
```

You can make methods in your application controller named `trash_url` and `trash_path` that just call and return the path from the generated methods mentioned above if you have a need to use those specific method names instead of the generated ones.

Comment: Ah, OK I get it now. I should have looked through my rake routes more carefully and seen that it was the way the route is named that I didn't understand.